# unable to make customized StepIndicator in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

im new to react native,i want to a stepIndicator exactly like in above [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNH2c.jpg).. But rn [StepIndicator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-step-indicator) is not looking good even though i cant increase the seperator height and i cant add some text in middle of steps like payment date etc.., titles also not aligning straight and i can only change colors and width of steps and seperators. So i tried to make customized StepIndicator but im unable to it.

const labels = [{title:"Order Subscribed",},{title:"Payment",},{title:"Dispatched",},{title:"site",}];

```
const stepIndicatorStyles = {
  stepIndicatorSize: 20,
  currentStepIndicatorSize:20,
  separatorStrokeWidth: 1,
  currentStepStrokeWidth: 20,
  stepStrokeCurrentColor: '#FFAA01',
  separatorFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
  separatorUnFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
  stepIndicatorFinishedColor: '#FFAA01',
  stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: '#636363',
  stepIndicatorCurrentColor: '#FFAA01',
  stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
  currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
  stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#000000',
  stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: '#FFAA01',
  stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
  labelColor: 'black',
  labelSize: 18,
  currentStepLabelColor: 'black'
}


In class in render() method..

 <StepIndicator
        customStyles={stepIndicatorStyles}
        currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition}
        stepCount={4} 
        direction='vertical'
        labels={labels.map(title => title.title)}
        />
```

Please help me to solve this. Im trying to get achieve this from 2 weeks but failed. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi.. did you get the answer ?

Comment: I am stuck in StepIndicator.. could you please help?

Comment: could you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424607/how-to-implement-custom-label-in-stepindicator-in-react-native'

Comment: sorry dude, i still couldnt found  any solution to display content inside steps...even though i am looking at this stepindicator librarary files to get any solution.. if i get to know i will write here...